# Parameter 0 of constructor 'java.lang.String' that could not be found

Tags: grails, groovy, resources, javabeans

My project developed by Grails 4, actually I am upgrading from Grails 2 to Grails 4. Can you suggest me a solution how can I solve it? Thanks

Error:

```
 Parameter 0 of constructor in com.bv.session.AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint required a bean of type
     'java.lang.String' that could not be found.
```

recourse.groovy:

```
beans = {

    authenticationEntryPoint(com.bv.session.AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
        loginFormUrl = '/login/auth' 
        grailsUrlMappingsHolder = ref('grailsUrlMappingsHolder')
        portMapper = ref('portMapper')
        portResolver = ref('portResolver')
    }

}
```

Class:

```
public class AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private UrlMappingsHolder proxyBean;
    public AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint(String loginFormUrl) {
        super(loginFormUrl);
    }

    @Override
    protected String determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(final HttpServletRequest request,
                                                     final HttpServletResponse response, final AuthenticationException e){

        String controllerName = (String)proxyBean.match(request.getServletPath()).getParameters().get("controller");

        String ajaxHeader = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("X-Requested-With");

        if ("XMLHttpRequest".equals(ajaxHeader)){
            return "/login/auth?session_expired_ajax=true";

        }

        if(request.getSession(false).isNew() || "index.gsp".equals(controllerName)) {
            return "/login/auth";
        }else{
            return "/login/auth?session_expired=true";
        }
    }

    public void setGrailsUrlMappingsHolder(UrlMappingsHolder proxyBean) {
        this.proxyBean = proxyBean;
    }
}
```

Tools:

- Grails 4
- Spring-security 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the
docs](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/spring.html#springdsl):

> ### 19.3 The BeanBuilder DSL Explained
>
> #### Using Constructor Arguments
>
> Constructor arguments can be defined using parameters to each
>   bean-defining method. Put them after the first argument (the Class):
>
> ```
> bb.beans {
>     exampleBean(MyExampleBean, "firstArgument", 2) {
>         someProperty = [1, 2, 3]
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This configuration corresponds to a `MyExampleBean` with a constructor that looks like this:
>
> ```
> MyExampleBean(String foo, int bar) {
>    ...
> }
> ```